# Is PostgreSQL extension pg_trgm safe to use in production?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-extensions

I have to implement text search functionality in my database. I believe trigram search will fit better than full-text search to my requirements(also PostgreSQL doesn’t support target language for full-text search). My question is does anyone use `pg_trgm`? How safe is it use it in production?

Comment: It is developed along with PostgreSQL, in the same source repository. How safe is PostgreSQL for production use?

Comment: Yes, you are right. My bad. I only read documentation and felt like it is seperate from main development and couldn’t be sure. Now, I am sure to use it. Thank you!